# Get class name by xtype

Tags: class, extjs, xtype

with Ext.ClassManager.get('Ext.panel.Panel') I get access to the origional class. But if I only have the xtype how do I get the same result? Ext.ClassManager.get('panel') is undefined

Thanks,
Arno

Comment: `Ext.ClassManager.get('Ext.panel.Panel')` is equal to `Ext.panel.Panel`. if you create a new item you simply add `Ext.create({xtype: 'panel'})`. From your question it does not make sense at all. Can you give us more insight?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by debugging Ext.create(...)
By adding **widget.** before the xtype-name I can call  Ext.ClassManager.getByAlias('widget.panel') to get the proper class.

Arno